# regex that matches a string that contains some text

Tags: python, regex

I need a regex that matches

```
re.compile('userpage')


href="www.example.com?u=userpage&as=233&p=1"
href="www.example.com?u=userpage&as=233&p=2"
```

I want to get all urls that have u=userpage and p=1

How can I modify the regex above to find both u=userpage and p=1?

Comment: it's like if you said *I'd like to go out. How do i jump from the window properly so I don't break my leg?*, when the better approach is to use your door. However, there's always more ways, how to do it..

Answer (score 5):

if you want to use, in my opinion, something more proper approach, than regexp:

```
from urlparse import *
urlparsed = urlparse('www.example.com?u=userpage&as=233&p=1')
# -> ParseResult(scheme='', netloc='', path='www.example.com', params='', query='u=userpage&as=233&p=1', fragment='')
qdict = dict(parse_qsl(urlparsed.query))
# -> {'as': '233', 'p': '1', 'u': 'userpage'}
qdict.get('p') == '1' and qdict.get('u') == 'userpage'
# -> True
```

Comment: @katrielalex what' you did not sees such thing yet? :) btw, originally it was: `from urlparse import urlparse, parse_qsl`, but i shortened it for sake of readability (it's not the key part, and `from urlparse import urlparse` is also not very aesthetical)

Comment: Heh, I know, don't worry. It's just one of those things like `don't parse HTML with regex` that come up an awful lot here. =p

Answer (score 4):

```
import lxml.html, urlparse

d = lxml.html.parse(...)
for link in d.xpath('//a/@href'):
    url = urlparse.urlparse(link)
    if not url.query:
        continue
    params = urlparse.parse_qs(url.query)
    if 'userpage' in params.get('u', []) and '1' in params.get('p', []):
        print link
```

Answer (score 2):

Regex is not a good choice for this because 1) the params could appear in either order, and 2) you need to do extra checks for query separators so that you don't match potential oddities like "flu=userpage", "sp=1", "u=userpage%20haha", or "s=123". (*Note:* I missed two of those cases in my first pass! So did others.) Also: 3) you already have a good URL parsing library in Python which does the work for you.

With regex you'd need something clumsy like:

```
q = re.compile(r'([?&]u=userpage&(.*&)?p=1(&|$))|([?&]p=1&(.*&)?u=userpage(&|$))')
return q.search(href) is not None
```

With urlparse you can do this. urlparse gives you a little more than you want but you can use a helper function to keep the result simple:

```
def has_qparam(qs, key, value):
    return value in qs.get(key, [])

qs = urlparse.parse_qs(urlparse.urlparse(href).query)
return has_qparam(qs, 'u', 'userpage') and has_qparam(qs, 'p', '1')
```

Comment: those `qs['u'] == 'userpage'` won't work, because `parse_qs` dict has list values.. might be then `'userpage' in qs['u']`.. or use `parse_qsl` (tuple) and convert to dict

Comment: Ah, yes, that's tripped me up in the past too :-P . Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

`/((u=userpage).*?(p=1))|((p=1).*?(u=userpage))/`

This will get all strings that contain the two bits you're looking for.

Comment: ugly and inefficient, but probably working :) btw, i'd insert `\>` after `p=1`'s

Comment: @mykhal, then you'd get an unusable RE (since it's not what Python REs use to indicate word boundaries -- there are many dialects of REs, and I think you're thinking about e.g. vim's).  If you used instead `\b`, like in my answer, you wouldn't have this problem (since it _is_ what Python REs use for the purpose;-).

Comment: @Alex Martelli, you *still* do have problems. See my comment on your answer.

Comment: @[Alex Martelli] you're right, sir, thanks. i do not use the boundary in python rex often, if ever.. :)

Comment: @downvoter: I think this regex works.  Did I say something incorrect?  Or was it just an answer you ideologically disagreed with?  If so, post a comment.

Comment: @Aaron, seen and answered.  And, how can you compare a pattern with `\>`, which will match **no** URLs of interest, with one with `\b`, which will falsely-match some values containing %-escapes?!

Comment: @Borealid, look at the comments on all of the other regex-using answers. You get a lot of false positives.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure you don't accidentally match parts like `bu=userpage`, `u=userpagezap`, `p=111` or `zap=1`, you need abundant use of the `\b` "word-boundary" RE pattern element.  I.e.:

```
re.compile(r'\bp=1\b.*\bu=userpage\b|\bu=userpage\b.*\bp=1\b')
```

The word-boundary elements in the RE's pattern prevent the above-mentioned, presumably-undesirable "accidental" matches.  Of course, if in your application they're *not* "undesirable", i.e., if you positively **want** to match `p=123` and the like, you can easily remove some or all of the word-boundary elements above!-)

Comment: `\b` doesn't protect you from everything. Your code still breaks on `?u=userpage%20whatever`.

Comment: @Aaron, true, %-escapes do introduce a word-boundary.  If you need to protect against that, `(\?|\&)' as "word start" and `(\&|$)` as "word end" might serve you better (or, unless you need portability across Python versions, you could use `parse_qs`, if you can correctly guess what module[s] it's in, in various versions of interest;-).

Comment: @Alex, why do you think `parse_qs` isn't portable? 2to3 fixes `urlparse` imports correctly.

Comment: @Aaron, it's been in `cgi_bin` "since forever", in `urlparse` only recently -- right now, at work, I'm focused on writing code supporting 2.4 to 2.7, _and_ future 2to3 runs, and there's enough headaches that avoidable ones are best avoided (sure, worst case, you can import "conditionally", that is, with try/except support, but I don't know how well that plays with 2to3).

Comment: @Alex, I pity you having to use 2to3 in ways it was not intended for.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to do this with string hacking, but you shouldn't. It's already in the standard library:

```
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> urllib.parse.parse_qs("u=userpage&as=233&p=1")
{'u': ['userpage'], 'as': ['233'], 'p': ['1']}
```

and hence

```
import urllib.parse
def filtered_urls( urls ):
    for url in urls:
        try:
            attrs = urllib.parse.parse_qs( url.split( "?" )[ 1 ] )
        except IndexError:
            continue

        if "userpage" in attrs.get( "u", "" ) and "1" in attrs.get( "p", "" ):
            yield url

foo = [ "www.example.com?u=userpage&as=233&p=1", "www.example.com?u=userpage&as=233&p=2" ]

print( list( filtered_urls( foo ) ) )
```

Note that this is Python 3 -- in Python `parse_qs` is in `urlparse` instead.

Comment: This raises a SyntaxError, and `'userpage' != ['userpage']`. Also, why not urlparse.urlparse to get the query out of the URL?

Comment: True, but a pretty trivial one (= for ==). Forgot about the lists though, thanks. And `urlparse` is fine, but overkill if we just want the query string.

Comment: `TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable`; you can't do `in` on `None`. Please *try* your solution before you post it.

Comment: Argh. I tried it and then changed the `None`s. +1 for being thorough, but I should point out that these are basically trivial bugs; if the OP wants to use the code they can easily fix the problems.

Comment: @killown: works fine for me. Did you forget to pass in `foo`?